# 65K ports and SSL?

Tags: port, http, ssl, https

People connect to bank using SSL.

Bank is opening its 443 port.

but there is only 1 port of 443 , but it is a server so I guess he is using also the other ports.

But that is means that it can only have ~65k connections at same time.

*Or*  , does it actually manage all the SSL requests on the *same* port(443) but opens  new thread for each request.

But that means that every customer will notice a big delay since there are other users which consume info .

I must be wrong here.

Is this how things done ?

Comment: And that's why you have more than one server.

Comment: @Nifle so whic part is the correct  , the first one or the second ? ( in my question)

Comment: Everybody uses the same port. And it your users experience delay because the webserver(s) can't keep up you add more servers.

Comment: @Nifle Im not a system guy , just asking.

Comment: No harm in asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be an infinite number of incoming connections to a single port (subject to OS implementation limits) as long as the other end can be identified with unique IP-port combinations. The server do not need to open a unique local port for each client. So the first bit if your second part is right.

Also, most operating systems can handle tens of thousands of threads without much perceived performance degredation. As long as the request handlers are coded with the usual concurrent programming requirements, the threads should be almost independent from each other. I guess most banking application will synchronise on a database as opposed to much in-memory objects, so the chance of a thread being blocked waiting for another is even lower.